# Float from json file returning 0 in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm currently new to Unity, and brand new to using web apis and json files with Unity.
I'm trying to display text on the screen which states the local temperature from a json file, but it keeps displaying 0.
My code:

```cs
private IEnumerator GetWeatherInfo()
{
    var www = new UnityWebRequest("http://api.weatherapi.com/v1/current.json?key=" 
        + API_key + "&q=" + latitude + "," + longitude)
    {
        downloadHandler = new DownloadHandlerBuffer()
    };

    yield return www.SendWebRequest();

    if (www.isNetworkError || www.isHttpError)
    {
        //error
        yield break;
    }

    Info = JsonUtility.FromJson<current>(www.downloadHandler.text);
    currentWeatherText.text = "Current weather: " + Info.temp_f;
}

[Serializable]
public class current
{
  public float temp_f;
}
```

**Here's the json file in question:**

[image: json file]

I suspect it may have something to do with the filename but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `current` class does not match with the JSON structure you receive ...

In the JSON you receive there are only two outer fields `location` and `current` so when the serializer searches for a field called `temp_f` on root level .. well there is none ;)

So you also have to mirror this nested structure and it should probably rather be

```
[Serializable] 
public class Root 
{ 
    public Current current; 
} 

[Serializable] 
public class Current 
{ 
    public float temp_f; 
}
```

and then use

```
Info = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(www.downloadHandler.text);
currentWeatherText.text = "Current weather: " + Info.current.temp_f;
```